# Mongodb - The $group stage takes longer when there are more documents in the database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have been getting into Mongo for the past few months and recently came across a problem I cannot seem to find any answers to. The situation is as follows -

- Database A - ~60m documents - Average document size 500B
- Database B - ~280k documents - Average document size 200B

The documents in Database B, are a subset of some documents from Database A but with different data in them. If I do a $match on both databases with the specific match conditions, both databases find the same amount of documents ~50k in roughly the same amount of time (Database B is a bit quicker but not massively).

The issues come with the next stages of my aggregation the $group, both documents are grouping on the exact same field and outputting a count for each group but the time it takes is massively different -

- Database A - ~50000ms
- Database B - ~ 1000ms

From what I have researched and understand amount Mongo, both of the $group stages should take much more similar times as the amount of documents being grouped is identical, although I understand the average documents sizes are slightly larger so that could add some time difference, but I think I must be missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: It'll help if you post the pipelines your using + schema's + index's on the collections, but from what it sounds to me your pipeline on database A is not utilising the index you think it should be using.

Comment: I would start by examining query plans for both of the queries in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a fix to increase the speed of my aggregation for Database A.

I found a thread that stated if you use an indexed $sort before a $group it should drastically increase the speed of the $group stage.

So I created a new index with the field which is being grouped by at the end of the index.

I then ran my aggregation again and it was just as quick as Database B, and this was without actually adding the $sort before the $group.

This is a little weird to me as from what I can find $group does not use indexes, but it seems to in this scenario, hope it helps someone.

Comment: the index also works on 'match'. @Nibbles are you using match before the group?